# Uninstalling some python packages deletes c:\Pythonxy link

Tags: python, windows, uninstallation, nose

Environment: Windows 7, Windows 10. 32 bits Python 2.7.9, 32 bits Python 3.4.2.

Issue: A couple python packages, notably ipython and nose, when uninstalled using e.g. "pip uninstall nose" also deletes the C:\Python27 / C:\Python34 link. Lots of tasks make use of these links, and fail to access any Python tool after the uninstall.

This happens consistently under either Windows 7 or Windows 10, under Python 2.7.9 or Python 3.4.2, with nose 1.3.4 or 1.3.7.

The behaviour is identical across a couple dozen different machines of highly various ages, both desktop machines and build agents.

Uninstalling ipython behaves the same way as uninstalling nose. Other packages uninstall without any such problems.

I am not myself doing Python development, but maintain a build environment for several projects using various tool versions. So, unistalling a Python package of one version to make room for another version is an everyday affair: On our build agents, a package of another version could (in principle) be installed for every build job executed. So we are completely dependent on automatic (i.e. scripted) and silent uninstall of the old version and install of the new one. No manual operations to clean up, reinstating the deleted link, is possible.

Any hints about how to handle this?

If anyone can give an explanation of WHY this happens, I'd be very curious!

Comment: Try uninstalling Windows. It's most likely the root of this and (many) other problems.

Comment: Why not just use virtualenv and thus get rid of such problems in the first place?

Comment: virtualenv cannot handle all the non-Python tools we are using